# How to read '.doc' file with python-docx module

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-docx, doc

I'm trying to read the .doc file with python-docx module ,
I'm doing

```
import docx

path = 'Sample-doc-file-100kb.doc'
doc = docx.Document(path) 
#extracting texts from doc
```

This works fine for .docx but gives  `ValueError: file 'Sample-doc-file-100kb.doc' is not a Word file, content type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.themeManager+xml'` error for .doc file.

I searched and found that this docx module doesn't work for older version of doc file. And I looked for converting the doc to docx but all the solution are windows dependent.

I'm running this code on aws-lambda so can't use those method .

Any way to either convert to doc to docx (platform independent) or to read .doc file?

Answer (score 0):

*convert to doc to docx (platform independent)*

If you are able to provide working LibreOffice or OpenOffice then you might try using [unoconv](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv) to do doc to docx conversion as it

> is a command line tool to convert any document format that LibreOffice
> can import to any document format that LibreOffice can export.

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu with this command:

```
apt-get install antiword
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).